# Insert a different value for each different row mysql

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to insert 37 different pictures for 37 different users in a database. It works but I always get same value in between the parenthesis.

```
$qty=37;
 for($i=1;$i < $qty;$i++){
$avatar = array('avatar ('.$i.').jpg');
 }
$target_file = 'uploads/'.$avatar[0];
$imageFileType='jpg';

while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($selectususers)){
           $IsPrimary = 1;
           $userid=$user['UserID'];
           $userimage1Q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO avatars 
           (UserID,PhotoPath,PhotoExtension,IsPrimaryPhoto) 
           VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
           $userimage1Q->bind_param("issi",$userid,$target_file,$imageFileType,$IsPrimary);
          $userimage1Q->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
 }
```

this gives the following result 37 times

```
uploads/avatar (36).jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
for ($i=1;$i < $qty;$i++) {
 $avatar = array('avatar ('.$i.').jpg');
}
```

With

```
$avatar = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < $qty; $i++) {
 $avatar[] = 'avatar(' . $i . ').jpg';
 $targetFile = 'uploads/' . $avatar[$i];
 // this array store all names 
}
print_r($avatar);
```

Comment: Hopefully you're not the one giving me the down vote because t it doesn't work. I get same kind of result when doing `$target_file = 'uploads/'.$avatar[0];` I get `uploads/avatar (1).jpg` 37 times.

Comment: Let me try it my self.

Comment: @SebastianFarham I updated the answer try now previously i was printing inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

It totally slipped my mind but the for loop is unnecessary. Everything can be handle in the while.

```
$i=1;
while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($selectususers)){$i++
$avatar = array('avatar ('.$i.').jpg');
$target_file = 'uploads/'.$avatar;
$imageFileType='jpg';
           $IsPrimary = 1;
           $userid=$user['UserID'];
           $userimage1Q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO avatars 
           (UserID,PhotoPath,PhotoExtension,IsPrimaryPhoto) 
           VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
           $userimage1Q->bind_param("issi",$userid,$target_file,$imageFileType,$IsPrimary);
          $userimage1Q->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
 }
```